# PHP date_diff() using strings

Tags: php, datetime

I have 2 dates that are created by concatenating 3 variables.

```
    $StartDate = $m . '/' . $dayy . '/' . $y;
    $EndDate = $m . '/' . $dayy . '/' . $y;

    $Interval = date_diff($StartDate , $EndDate)
    $NumOfDays = $interval->format('%a');
    $NumOfDays++;
```

I get the error that date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface.

I've searched this site and found something that did not work.

```
    $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $StartOfWeek);
    $a = $date->getTimestamp(); 

    $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $EndOfWeek);
    $b = $date->getTimestamp();

    $interval = date_diff($a, $b);
    $NumOfDays = $interval->format('%a');
```

I'm getting the error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean

How do I properly convert the 2 dates of type string to DateTime?

Comment: Your format seems to be "month/day/year" but you are trying to parse it as day/month/year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your date strings to create [`DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. You do not need to use `date_create_from_format()` as your date format is recognized by PHP as a standard date format.

```
$m = 5;
$dayy = 20;
$y = 2020;

$m2 = 4;
$dayy2 = 18;
$y2 = 2020;

$StartDate = new DateTime($m . '/' . $dayy . '/' . $y);
$EndDate = new DateTime($m2 . '/' . $dayy2 . '/' . $y2);

$interval = date_diff($StartDate , $EndDate);
$NumOfDays = $interval->format('%a');
echo $NumOfDays;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lTNBG)

Comment: Thanks much. That is rather simple.